# viewport "maximum-scale=1" its not working in firefox

Tags: html, responsive-design, viewport

I'm using this viewport below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

As you see, I don't want to allow users to make zoom in their devices with maximum-scale="1".

I'm testing in my smartphone, and this viewport is working fine on google chrome browser, but when I test in firefox I'm able to make zoom.

Do you know why? And how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Under content add "..., user-scalable=no' />"

Straight from the horse's mouth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

HTH